# JSON object is treated as string

Tags: javascript, json

I have an ajax call that returns the following JSON:

```
returnedData = "[ 
    { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', address: '123 Spa Road', city: 'London', 
        orders: 
        [ 
            { product: 'TV', price: 599.99, quantity: 2, orderTotal: 1199.98 } 
        ]
    }
]";

var customers = JSON.parse (returnedData);
console.log(customers.length); // prints length of the string data
```

It treats it as string. However, it I assign the result directly.

```
var customers = [ 
    { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', address: '123 Spa Road', city: 'London', 
        orders: 
        [ 
            { product: 'TV', price: 599.99, quantity: 2, orderTotal: 1199.98 } 
        ]
    }
];

console.log(customers.length); // prints 1 - the number of objects
```

Why is it like this? How can I assign it dynamically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `prints length as string`

Comment: The way that code is written, it will not return anything but an error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: That's not valid JSON. It would be a valid Javascript literal, but it's not JSON.

Comment: it prints the number of characters in the customers variable

Comment: JSON has double quotes around every key. Yours doesn't

Comment: The code isn't even valid JavaScript since you cannot have multiline strings in JS.

Comment: `[{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","address":"123 Spa Road","city":"London","orders":[{"product":"TV","price":599.99,"quantity":2,"orderTotal":1199.98}]}]` is valid JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have problems with you string...

here is your well formed json

```
var returnedData ='[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "address": "123SpaRoad",
        "city": "London",
        "orders": [
            {
                "product": "TV",
                "price": 599.99,
                "quantity": 2,
                "orderTotal": 1199.98
            }
        ]
    }
]';
```

single quotes must be escaped or don't use them... you can use them when you open and close the string so its more well formed than other posibilitys (correted because of useful comment from @Victor Canova)

Comment: you can always check your json code here: [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Just curious, "single quotes arent allowed" you meant that they must be scaped if used inside JSON, right?

Answer (score 3):

Run the code through http://jsonlint.com/ and you will find out you have errors in your code.

Pasting your object literal into the validator you will see

```
Parse error on line 2:
[    {        id: 1,        first
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

You need to have double quotes around the name and string values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the attributes with double quotes:

```
var returnedData = '[{ "id": 1, "firstName": "John"}]';
```

Answer (score 1):

`returnedData` isn't a valid JSON message (attributes are not wrapped with double quotes), but you can treat it as JS doing

```
var customers = eval(returnedData);
```

If you want to use `JSON.parse`, correct the `returnedData`.

Answer (score 1):

The string you're receiving isn't a valid JSON object. Be careful not to confuse JSON and JavaScript. Look at this example:

```
var returnedData = '[ { "id": 1, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "address": "123 Spa Road", "city": "London", "orders": [ { "product": "TV", "price": 599.99, "quantity": 2, "orderTotal": 1199.98 } ] } ]';

var customers = JSON.parse (returnedData);
console.log(customers.length); // the correct length now.
```

Note that the only difference is that I put the keys in the dictionary within "'s.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was missing.